# Interacting regressors in a BQ ML Linear Regression Model

Tags: r, google-bigquery, regression

I'm trying to work out how get two regressors to interact when using BigQuery ML.

In this example below (apologies for the rough fake data!), I'm trying to predict `total_hire_duration` using `trip_count` as well as the month of the year. BQ tends to treat the `month` part as a constant to add on to the linear regression equation but I actually want it to grow with `trip_count`. For my real dataset I can't just supply the timestamp as BQML seems to over parametise.

I should add, if I supply `month` as a numeric value I just get a single coefficient that doesn't really work for my dataset (patterns form around parts of the academic year rather than calendar).

If the month part is a constant, then as `trip_count` gets very very large, the constant in the equation `y = ax+b` becomes inconsequential. It's almost as if I want something like `y = ax + bx + c` where `a` is the `trip_count` and `b` is a coefficient weighted on what the value of `month` is.

This is quite easy to do in R, I'd just run
`glm(bike$totalHireDuration ~ bike$tripCount:bike$month)`

Here's some fake data to reproduce:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE MODEL
  my_model_name OPTIONS (model_type='linear_reg',
    input_label_cols =['total_hire_duration']) AS (
  SELECT
    CAST(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATE(start_date)) AS STRING) month,
    COUNT(*) trip_count,
    SUM(duration_sec) total_hire_duration
  FROM
    bigquery-public-data.san_francisco_bikeshare.bikeshare_trips
  GROUP BY
    date)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, note that it is almost always a bad idea to fit a model such as:

```
glm(bike$totalHireDuration ~ bike$tripCount:bike$month)
```

which fits only the interaction without the main effects.

But getting to the point of the question, I can't help with big query in particular, but in any software you can fit an interaction between two variables simply by creating a new variable that is the product of the two and then using that as a regressor.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the `month` in your model is string. So the BQML linear regression model will treat it as a categorical feature. If you want month as an integer, you can try `CAST(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATE(start_date)) AS INT64) month`